# MySQL Find and Replace (Delete) Regex in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, regex, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to perform a find and replace (actually, a delete) on a particular column in a MySQL database (circa 20k+ records) where the column in question contains HTML (the body text for page content in a CMS).

I need to find and replace/delete the following text from within each record and leave all of the other HTML intact (the below string appears only once per record):

```
<h2>Location Map</h2><p><a href="[?]" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">[?]</a></p>
```

Where "[?]" is a string of variable content and length (both alphanumeric  and symbols) and the rest static content exactly as it's shown above.

I know this should be very simple and a bit of a stupid question but I'm no regular expression expert and can't quite work out what I'm doing wrong (possible not escaping enough characters or too many).

Preferably I'd like a regex I can use in phpMyAdmin to perform the find and replace.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: MariaDB has `REGEXP_REPLACE`, MySQL does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find/replace statement in PHP could be something like this:

```
$regex = '#<h2>Location Map</h2><p><a href="(.*?)" onclick="window.open.*?>(.*?)</a></p>#';
$result = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $html);
```

...where *$html* would be the original data you retrieve from your database, and *$replace* the value you want to insert instead of the matched string.

For instance, if:

```
$html = 'all that comes before
<h2>Location Map</h2><p><a href="http://www.foofle.com" onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;">Foofle</a></p>
all that comes after';

$replace = "(link=$1, text=$2)";

$result = preg_replace($regex, $replace, $html);
echo $result;
```

Outputs:

> all that comes before
>   (link=http://www.foofle.com, text=Foofle)
>   all that comes after